# Slide 3 li items using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a `div` box with a `ul` list and I want to show 3 `li` items one under each other and then `slide`/`toggle` another 3 items from my list.

For example in my `ul` I will have 9 `li` items, but I what to show only 3 items first and then upon clicking a next button i will the next three and upon clicking the previous button I will see the last 3 in the list.

Is this possible?

My sample code:

```
<ul>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 4</li>
    <li>item 5</li>
    <li>item 6</li>
    <li>item 7</li>
    <li>item 8</li>
    <li>item 9</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: it might easier to split them into 3 lists, rather than have them all under a single `ul` element

Answer (score 5):

```js
$('.itemsList').each(function() {
  
  const group = 3; // group 3 by 3
  const $items = $(this).find('li');
  const $btns = $(this).find('.prev, .next');
  const max = Math.ceil($items.length / group);
  let c = 0;
  
  function showItems(ev) {
    c = c<0 ? max-1 : c%max;
    $items.hide().slice(group*c, group*c+group).show();
  }
  
  $btns.on('click', function() {
    $(this).is('.next') ? ++c : --c;
    showItems();
  });
  
  showItems(); // init
});
```

```html
<div class="itemsList">
  <ul id="myList">
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 4</li>
    <li>item 5</li>
    <li>item 6</li>
    <li>item 7</li>
    <li>item 8</li>
    <li>item 9</li>
  </ul>
  <button type="button" class="prev">prev</button>
  <button type="button" class="next">next</button>
</div>

<div class="itemsList">
  <ul id="myList">
    <li>item 1 (Example with 5 items)</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 4</li>
    <li>item 5</li>
  </ul>
  <button type="button" class="prev">prev</button>
  <button type="button" class="next">next</button>
</div>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this

*[**jsFiddle Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/PAEms/1/)*

```
$('#next').click(function(){
    var index = $('ul li:visible').last().index() +2
    $('ul li:visible').slideUp().last().nextUntil(':nth-child('+index+'n+3)').slideDown();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
var showNumber = 3;
var startPos = 0;
var endPos = showNumber;
var $List = $('ul li');
$List.hide().slice(startPos ,endPos).fadeIn();


$('a').click( function() {
    startPos = startPos + showNumber;
    endPos = endPos + showNumber;
    $List.hide().slice(startPos ,endPos).fadeIn();
    return false;
});
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/YURck/

Basicly what it does, it sets a number of how many to show at a time (showNumber), then determines the start and end index to slice.

To extend it you could make an check on the length so you can hide the "next" link when you are the last set of elements.

Hope it helps :)